# No provider for NgControl inside CustomDirective despite imported forms modules Angular2+

Tags: angular, forms, dependency-injection, import, angular-directive

So, i'm creating a custom directive and need to use form-controls into it. But i'm getteng an error:
No provider for NgControl; I know that the right answer is: import reactive forms module but i've already imported !

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms'
@Directive({
  selector: '[testDirective]'
})
export class TestDirectiveClass implements OnDestroy{

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, c: NgControl ) { }

    ngOnDestroy() {

  }

}
```

my component:

```
<p testDirective>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

and my appModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TestDirectiveClass } from './testDirective.directive';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, TestDirectiveClass ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bjjotr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being thrown, because the `p` element missing the `[formControlName]` directive. The next thing is to use HTML form elements, like `input, select, radio button, etc.` This is because Angular defines `ControlValueAccessor` for the default form elements, while `p` is used only for representation of text, it doesn't have abilities like an `input`.

app.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <input testDirective formControlName="testControl">
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      testControl: [null]
    })
  }
}
```

Also the Angular documentation says the following:

*A base class that all control FormControl-based directives extend. It binds a FormControl object to a DOM element.*

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Decorator** [@Optional](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional).

*Parameter decorator to be used on constructor parameters, which marks the parameter as being an optional dependency. The DI framework provides null if the dependency is not found.*

```js
import { Directive, Optional, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms'
@Directive({
  selector: '[testDirective]'
})
export class TestDirectiveClass implements OnDestroy{

  constructor(
    @Optional() public c: NgControl,
   private elementRef: ElementRef  ) { }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjr7q7

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! What it changes ? I mean, for me it's a strange behaviour cause i've seen solutions without any decorators, just with importing and init into a constructor. But now it seems doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work? It's to avoid to not find any module when you compile (especially with AOT)